# specify global-abbrev-table in a separate file

Tags: abbrev, configuration-files

I know one can define where abbrev files are saved with something like this

```
(setq abbrev-file-name "/home/zeltak/.emacs.d/abbrv/personal_abbrv.txt")
```

but this file has several section like `(define-abbrev-table 'Buffer-menu-mode-abbrev-table '())` etc.

Is there a way to define another file that will only record the `global-abbrev-table`, is that possible at all?

Comment: You could just `(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table '())` in some file, let's say `abbrevs.el` and at the end of it `(provide 'abbrevs)`. Afterwards you just `(require 'abbrevs)`.

Comment: I agree with @caisah, and I would recommend looking into Emacs' file loading functions for more fine-grained control.  I think `provide/require` as mentioned would be the easiest if you're unfamiliar with Emacs Lisp.